# why Python zipfile doesn't unzip these files?

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I have some code that works for some files but not others. I am baffled! I took the same file and copied ten times with different names to simulate a production case.

The files would be in two different paths. path_one works, but path_two doesn't.

```
import zipfile

path_one = "/tmp/my_files_one"
path_two = "/tmp/my_files_two"

for file in os.listdir(path_one):
    print("xx", file)
#    if zipfile.is_zipfile(file):
#        print("in here")
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') as zipo:
        zipo.extractall(path=path_one)
```

but if I use path_two, I get this error:

```
xx file_two.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./this_script.py", line 95, in <module>
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') as zipo:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 923, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, modeDict[mode])
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file_two.zip'
```

The file is most certainly in the path. I had uncommented the is_zipfile part because it wasn't true, even though it's true for other files.

Why??

Comment: "but if I use path_two...."  can you paste the exact code you use for path_two? It is usually best to give Stack Overflow the broken code to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be using a relative path, and your running the command from /tmp/my_files_one so that becomes the current working directory.

Try using os.path.join(dir, file) to get the absolute path to the file

```
import zipfile

path_one = "/tmp/my_files_one"
path_two = "/tmp/my_files_two"

for file in os.listdir(path_two):
    file = os.path.join(path_two, file)
    print("xx", file)
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(file):
        print("in here")
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') as zipo:
        zipo.extractall(path=path_two)
```

Comment: yeah, os.path.join works now. Although I swear my script worked on some files as above. Weird. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Your script should have worked for any files that were in the current working directory when you ran the script. And not for files that were not in the current working directory.